# Problem with package in Vite + Inertia + Laravel

Tags: vue.js, vite

I'm using the package `vue-pdf-embed`.

When I run `npm run build` I got the next error:

```
[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "vue-pdf-embed" from "resources/js/Pages/Scan/PDF.vue".
This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
`build.rollupOptions.external`
```

So, I edited the vite.config.js, added the next lines:

```
 build: {
      rollupOptions: {
        external: ['vue-pdf-embed']
      }
    }
```

And now it compiles perfect.

But when I access to my page, in the console I got the next error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue-pdf-embed". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I saw the `./node_modules` and my packages has disappear. If I removed the lines on `vite.config.js` I got the package but it doesn't compile.

What I need to do to make it works?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
If anyone has the same problem.

- remove new lines in vite.config.js
- rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
- update npm and node to last versions
- npm install
- npm run build

all run correctly